# MySQL: increment and reset a variable in IF statement when updating row

Tags: mysql, if-statement

In the commande below:

```
SET @var=1; UPDATE characters SET tmp =  IF(isRadical=1, @var=1, @var:=@var+1);
```

I'm expecting `@var` and `tmp` column to be reset to `1` when the column `isRadical=1` for a row, and incrementing otherwise. But what I get instead is that `tmp` is always incremented and never reset to `1`, when `isRadical=1`, then `tmp` is set to `0` for the given row only.

What's wrong in this command ?

Comment: You have a typo in the IF: @var=1 should be @var:=1 (you missed the colon)

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Thanks, it's now working!